# С# List<T> .Как запомнить номер индекса у элементов списка, чтобы при удаление некоторых элементов, у старых оставался тот же самый индекс

Tags: c#, list

Такой вопрос, у меня есть программа:

```
List<int> s = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
for(int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
}
  if(s[i]$2!=0)
  {
    s.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
foreach(int i in s)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s[i]);
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы когда я удалю нечетные элементы из списка, у старых элементов остался тот же индекс, что и до удаления, каким образом это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Индексы в `List<>` не могут остаться после удаления такими же, так как все элементы смещаются. Пара вариантов:

1. Не удалять, а вставлять `null` и при выводе игнорировать:

   ```
   // Иницилизация
   List<int?> s = new List<int?>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
   // Удаление
   for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++) {
       if (s[i] % 2 != 0)
           s[i] = null;
   }
   // Вывод
   for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
   {
       if (s[i] != null)
           Console.WriteLine("s[{0}] = {1}", i, s[i]);
   }
   ```
2. Использовать `Dictionary<>` или `SortedDictionary<>`:

   ```
   // Иницилизация
   var d = new Dictionary<int, int>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
       d.Add(i, i + 1);
   }
   // Удаление
   d = d.Where(kvp => kvp.Value % 2 == 0)
        .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);
   // Или вместо Where
   /*int[] keys = new int[d.Count];
   d.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);
   foreach (int i in keys)
   {
       if (d[i] % 2 != 0)
           d.Remove(i);
   }*/
   // Вывод
   foreach (int i in d.Keys)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("d[{0}] = {1}", i, d[i]);
   }
   ```
3. Сохранять индексы отдельно. Как @Igor в отдельный список.